# Java code with tests - infinite loop?

Tags: java

I try to get the relationship between people. However, when I run unit test, the test runs forever, it doesn't get the result and my CPU usage was high.
Could someone see what's wrong with my code?

The string relations are multiple line inputs of string with in the format of `"A , B C , D"` where `A` is the parent of `B` and `C` is the parent of `D`.

This is the default constructor for the code and the input in string format. We don't need to check if the format is correct:

```
public SeeRelations(String relations){
    this.relations = relations;
}
```

This the helper function to get each line of the string from the formatted input:

```
//helper function to get each line of the string
private ArrayList<String> lineRelations(){
    int i;
    ArrayList<String> lineRelations = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] lines = relations.split("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
        lineRelations.add(lines[i]);
    }
    return lineRelations;
}
```

This is the function to put all the relations from the input formatted string to arraylists:

```
//helper function to put each of the relationship in arraylists
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allRelations(){
    int i;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allRelations = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> lineRelations = lineRelations();
    for(i = 0; i < lineRelations.size(); i++){
        ArrayList<String> eachLine = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(lineRelations.get(i).split("\\s*,\\s*")));
        allRelations.add(eachLine);
    }
    return allRelations;
}
```

This is the method to check if the input name exists:

```
//helper function to see if the name exist for seeRelations()
private boolean hasThisName(String name){
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allRelations = allRelations();
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i = 0; i < allRelations.size(); i++){
        for(j = 0; j < allRelations.get(i).size(); j++){
            if(name.equals(allRelations.get(i).get(j))){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is the function to get the generation number between two people:

```
//helper function to get Generation number of seeRelations()
private int getGenerationNum(String person, String ancestor){
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allRelations = allRelations();
    String name;
    int i;
    int j;
    int generationNum = 0;
    for(i = 0, j = 0, name = ancestor; i < allRelations.size(); i++){
        if(name.equals(allRelations.get(i).get(0)) && !person.equals(allRelations.get(i).get(1))){
            generationNum++;
            ancestor = allRelations.get(i).get(1);
            i = 0;
            j = 1;
        }
        else if(ancestor.equals(allRelations.get(i).get(0)) && person.equals(allRelations.get(i).get(1))){
            generationNum++;
            j = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(j == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return generationNum;
    }
}
```

This is the method to get multiple of `"great"` for the final output:

```
private String great(int num){
    int i;
    String great = "";
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
        great += "great";
    }
    return great;
}
```

This is my final method to check the relationship between two people:

```
public String SeeRelations(String person, String ancestor){
    int generationNum = getGenerationNum(person, ancestor);
    String great = great(generationNum  - 2);
    if(!(hasThisName(person) && hasThisName(ancestor))){
        return null;
    }
    else{
        if(generationNum == 0){
            return null;
        }
        else if(generationNum == 1){
            return ancestor + " is the parent of " + person;
        }
        else if(generationNum == 2){
            return ancestor + " is the grandparent of " + person;
        }
        else{
            return ancestor + " is the" + " " +  great +"grandparent of " + person;
          }
    }
}
```

This is my test cases, And it runs forever and couldn't get a result

```
public class FamilyTreeTest {

    @Test
    public void testSeeRelations() {
        FamilyTree relation2 = new FamilyTree("John Doe ,   Mary Smith" + "\n" + "Martin Weasel ,  John Doe");
        assertEquals("Martin Weasel is the grandparent of Mary Smith", familyTree2.SeeRelations("Mary Smith", "Martin Weasel"));
    }
```

Comment: sorry, bu it seems my question is totally screwed up by my style of input...could someone delete this question and I will re-ask it when I edit the format correctly

Comment: Edit your post, and format it correctly. Text should be formatted as text, and code should be formatted as code. Not the reverse.

Comment: AFAIK, you should be able to edit your own question. Just click the edit link below the question.

Comment: Fixed some of the most grievous formatting issues. Basically, make sure there is a blank line between a non-code line and the start of a block of code.

Comment: OK, I just started to edit the question and got vaccumed inside :) [OCD](http://www.google.co.il/url?q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%25E2%2580%2593compulsive_disorder&sa=U&ei=FV2pUM_XE8aUswb-loHIDg&ved=0CA8QFjAC&usg=AFQjCNHTgJ3q5wIeCKOPXGsGZ0UiwOowXA)

Comment: How many people and relationships are there in your input? Have you tried your algorithm with a small test data set? It may be that your code is fine but your problem isn't feasible because the time it takes increases exponentially or factorially as the input size increases.

Comment: Also, you should be able to eliminate some of your code from suspicion yourself with some simple testing... unless you are using a big data set and not logging anything out or using a debugger. If so, use a small test data set that you've created so that you know what the output should be and try a few debugging prints or your debugger.

Comment: i might be wrong, but your code doesn't look like has infinite loop, BUT almost each method calls allRelations() method, and all those operations on string and creating array might be slow especially if you have large input, second thing, are you sure is it working? by any chance your seerelation() returned null which is ignored somewhere? could you provide your testcase as well?

Comment: I repost my qustion, here is the URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445184/could-some-help-me-find-why-my-code-couldnt-run

Comment: @user902383   I added the test case at the last, could you give me a help?

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(i = 0, j = 0, name = ancestor; i < allRelations.size(); i++){
            if(name.equals(allRelations.get(i).get(0)) && !person.equals(allRelations.get(i).get(1))){
                generationNum++;
                ancestor = allRelations.get(i).get(1);
                i = 0;
                j = 1;
            }
            else if(ancestor.equals(allRelations.get(i).get(0)) && person.equals(allRelations.get(i).get(1))){
                generationNum++;
                j = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
```

here you have your faulty lines
in your case your ancestor/name is "Martin Weasel" given relation for martin is "John Doe", but you are looking for mary smith so `name.equals(allRelations.get(i).get(0)) && !person.equals(allRelations.get(i).get(1)))` this is `true` and this  `i = 0;` makes your loop starts from beginning

what you could do, try to create object person
ie
class Person{
String name;
List childrens;
List parents;
...
}
then just do simple tree walker

```
int SearchDown(Person person, String searchedRelation,int generation)
{
if person.getName().equals(searchedRelation())
return generation;
for (Person child: person.getChildren())
{
int generation = SearchDown(child, searchedRelation, generation+1);
if (generation!=-1) return generation;
}
return -1;
}
```

etc...

i'm really finding this way much easier to deal with all types of trees